# How to control a parallel OLED graphics display

Tags: display, dot-matrix-display

I'm thinking of using a matrix OLED display like [this one.](http://www.vishay.com/docs/37707/oled050h016a.pdf) This display uses a parallel interface very similar to those I've seen on text LCD displays, so I assume I'd control it in a similar way. However, the more I think about it, the less sense it makes.

Essentially my question is this: How would I set certain pixels on this display? And does anyone know of a reference for the various instructions I can send to it?

Thanks!

By the way, I noticed in the data sheet it has a built in controller called "OLED-0010". Is this of any relevance?

Comment: This question is too broad for stack exchange.  Classically you read the data sheet / programmers manual.  But today first do some web searching on the controller chip, display name, etc as it is likely someone has already written a driver library perhaps for Arduino.  It's often good to check these things before purchase...  You might consider the common 128x32 I2C interfaced OLED with an SSD1306 as an alternative since it is well supported.

Comment: This https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/oled-display-hookup-guide/all will work with your OLED display.

Comment: @G36 the asker's OLED is graphic, you linked to a tutorial for a character display.

Comment: @ChrisStratton the datasheet is very limited, the best it gives me is the name of each pin. I can't find any information about the controller, unfortunately.

Comment: Rule #1 is not to buy something for which you cannot obtain sufficient information.   There are plenty of small and medium sized displays well supported by example code available today.

Comment: @ChrisStratton That is true. In fact, I found another display, similar to that one, but which I can find information for (different controller though so the information won't be compatible). Anway I'll probably just get that one instead, even though it's not _as_ suitable for my specific application.

Should I delete this question? Since I agree that it's too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably [this rebranded Winstar display](https://www.winstar.com.tw/products/oled-module/graphic-oled-display/50x16-oled.html). The controller is [WS0010](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS0010.pdf). It is HD44780 compatible, but additionally has graphics mode.

Comment: +1. Beat me to it. I was just about to post [this](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS0010.pdf) link from Adafruit. For what it's worth, I found this by searching "OLED-0010 controller" and it was the first result.